# Android ListView with alternate color and on focus color

Tags: android, listview, colors, alternate

I need to set alternate color in list view rows but when i do that it removes/ disables the on focus default yellow background

I tried with backgroundColor
rowView.setBackgroundColor(SOME COLOR);

also with backgrounddrwable.

> ```
> rowView.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.view_odd_row_bg);
> ```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
      android:state_window_focused="false"
      android:drawable="@color/odd" />

   <!--
      Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states
      so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed
      state.
   -->
   <item
      android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_enabled="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/highlight" />
   <item
      android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_enabled="false"
      android:drawable="@color/highlight" />

   <item
      android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/highlight" />
   <item
      android:state_focused="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/highlight" />

   <item
      android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@color/highlight" />

</selector>
```

but it wont work.

is there any way we can set background color and on focus color simultaneously which will work.

Answer (score 6):

I found this tutorial to be very helpful for me.

http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/

I was able to make the ListView items have alternating colors plus the focused item kept the default highlighted color.

Comment: How can i do that using bindView?

I've tried something like this:

int i = 0;

view.setBackgroundResource(i%2==0 ? R.drawable.bindview_bg_gray : R.drawable.bindview_bg_white);

i++;

but after a few scrolls it gets all messy!

Comment: Extremely late comment, but for posterity: Philipz is relying on sequential calling of bindView, which you just should not do. Never assume anything about the order of bindView calls. Instead try to do the modulo operation on cursor.getPosition() (cursor being one of the params of the bindView method).

Answer (score 2):

Put a transparency in your color, the yellow highlighting is still there, it is just behind your background color, a transparency will let it show through.